# Updates to blocks not visible to anonymous users

Tags: views, blocks, users

I've recently put an update to the blocks on my site - they show for me when I'm logged in, but not for anonymous users. The previous arrangement of blocks remains visible, but without the additional text-only block I've added along with the rearrangement of others.

I've checked the permissions and it should be visible, yet they're not showing. I've tried certain fixes that we're outlined on other threads to no avail.

I am using Drupal 6

Any ideas?

Comment: Sanity check: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache.

Comment: certainly sounds like a typical case of page caching.  do you have an external cache such as Varnish that might be holding onto them?

Comment: Sounds like someting along the lines of a Varnish cache issue like Jimajamma brought up.

Comment: Or even simpler - browser's cache? Or maybe it's Boost that didn't get cleared? Boost cache is NOT cleared on cache clear all, afair.